# Manipulating timezones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issues with timezones and importing dates from different zones in my application, the zones are for the `Availability` model.

On the UI end of things I have bootstrap datetimepicker and that creates `params[start_time]` but it doesn't have a specific zone associated with it.

The Availability belongs to a `Venue` which has an timezone. I've been wondering if there was a way I could do something like:

```
# Explicitly set zone based on Venue.time_zone
start_date_zoned = set_time_zone_to(param[:start_date], Venue.time_zone)

# Convert start_date to UTC to standardize with DB default
start_date_zoned.utc
```

The reason I need to make this conversion is because I have this scope on `Availabilities` that's not returning correctly because the zones are off:

```
scope :after_now, -> {where{start_time >= Time.zone.now }} 
# Maybe Time.zone.now isn't right?
```

For example if I have 2 different times imported from 2 users in different timezones

1. start_date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 22:00:00 "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
2. start_date: Mon, 19 Oct 2015 22:00:00 "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"

When that datetime is coming through the params, it doesn't  have the zone, just the date and it's stored as: `Mon, 19 Oct 2015 22:00:00 UTC`

When I do `Availabilities.after_now` and  say it's currently `21:00 UTC`, both results would come up but in reality, given that those two imported availabilities should have been EST and PST (then converted to their correct UTC value), they might or might not actually be `after_now`

Is there a way to do this at all, am I making any sense?

Comment: This is an old blog post but covers a lot of things that are good to know about Rails/timezones: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this blog post which covers the nitty-gritty of what you should be aware of when working with multiple timezones:

http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

From the article, one solution for you would be to use the current request to the active timezone, active being `Venue.time_zone`. Something like:

```
around_filter :venue_time_zone, :if => :venue?

def venue?
  @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
end

def venue_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone(@venue.time_zone, &block)
end
```

Then update your scope:

```
scope :after_now, -> {where{start_time >= Time.current }}
```

And that should respect the timezone thats set for the current request.

Another solution would be to pass in the `Venue` to your `scope`:

```
scope :after_now, -> { |venue| where{start_time.in_time_zone(venue.time_zone) >= Time.now.in_time_zone(venue.time_zone) }}
```

Comment: I have an around filter for user's specifically `around_filter :user_time_zone, if: :current_user` If I'm trying to make sure availabilities are saved using the `Venue.time_zone` would I do `around_filter :avail_time_zone, if :availability?`

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution, which is to pass in the Venue into your scope and do your logic on that.

Comment: I'm not sure about the `around filter`. Example: If this is my date `2015-12-19 16:00` how does Rails/Ruby know that this date is in the Venue's time zone? From what I understand, what you have above would `convert` it to the venue's time zone from an assumed default. I'm trying to find a way to say that if given that date string above, how do I say, `hey, this is 2015-12-19 16:00 Eastern change it to UTC or hey this is 2015-12-19 16:00 Pacific change it to UTC`

Comment: @batman look at my update to the scope. The key is just running your timestamp thru `.in_time_zone(venue.time_zone)`